# Remember Me Page - Unexpected End of File error

Tags: php, eof, brackets

I have a page that remembers the users name.  But it tells me that there is an unexpected end of file.  I looked for missing brackets, found one, added it, but now it tells me theres an unexpected bracket (by the session end).
Any help???

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Remember UserName</title>
<?PHP
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];

        if ($username == $_POST['username']) {
            print "Welcome back, ". " $username ";
            print "Would you like to log out?";
            echo '<form action="Logout" method="post">
            <Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Logout" Value = "Logout">
            </FORM>';

        }
        else {
            print ("You're not logged in to this site");
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['Logout'])) {
        $Logout = $_POST['Logout'];

        if ($Logout == $_POST['Logout']) 
            print "You are now logged out";
            session_destroy()
    }    
?>
</head>
<body>
<Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="index.php">
<Input Type = "text" Value ="username" Name ="username">
<Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value = "Login">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to normally format your code and look closely to indentation. you'll see your mistakes.

Comment: This is why you indent your code! 1. you're setting `$Logout` and then testing it against the value you just assigned...why? 2. I'm guessing you want braces around that logout code? These things become quite apparent when you properly format / indent your code. Did I mention you should *indent your code* ?

Comment: why are you assigning the value of `$_POST['Logout']` and then immediately checking if its what you just assigned...? You're also missing braces around that logout code - you can only use that shorthand syntax when your conditional block is one line.

Comment: @sevenseacat Looks like we're on the same page tonight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
session_destroy()
                 ^-- right there
```

is missing a closing semi-colon

```
session_destroy();
```

Which is the cause for the `Unexpected End of File error` error message.

---

**Notes:**

Using your present code, you may very well get the following error message: (*which I tested*)

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at...

It's best to use the following method, placing `session_start();` above any output:

*Sidenote*: I am uncertain why you're using `session_start();` in your code, since there are no session variables in your posted code. If you're not going to be using something to the effect of `$username=$_SESSION['username'];` then you can safely remove it.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Remember UserName</title>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];

if ($username == $_POST['username']) {
print "Welcome back, ". " $username ";
print "Would you like to log out?";
echo '<form action="Logout" method="post">
<Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Logout" Value = "Logout">
</FORM>';

}
else {
print ("You're not logged in to this site");
}
}

if (isset($_POST['Logout'])) {
$Logout = $_POST['Logout'];

if ($Logout == $_POST['Logout']) 
        print "You are now logged out";
        session_destroy();
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="index.php">
<Input Type = "text" Value ="username" Name ="username">
<Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value = "Login">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Additional notes:**

I also noticed a few discrepencies in your logout button.

This `echo '<form action="Logout" method="post">`

should be replaced with `echo '<form action="" method="post">`

(*unless you're using an actual file, yet this seems to be most unlikely*)

*Plus*, you can narrow this down:

```
if (isset($_POST['Logout'])) {
    $Logout = $_POST['Logout'];

    if ($Logout == $_POST['Logout']) 
        print "You are now logged out";
        session_destroy();
}
```

to:

```
if (isset($_POST['Logout'])) {
        print "You are now logged out";
        session_destroy();
}
```

---

**Complete rewrite:**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Remember UserName</title>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];

if ($username == $_POST['username']) {
    print "Welcome back, ". " $username ";
    print "Would you like to log out?";
    echo '<form action="" method="post">
        <Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Logout" Value = "Logout">
</form>';

}
else {
    print ("You're not logged in to this site");
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['Logout'])) {
    print "You are now logged out";
    session_destroy();
  }
?>
</head>
<body>
<form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="">
<Input Type = "text" Value ="username" Name ="username">
<Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value = "Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plus, I double checked the OP's bracing matches, and it's fine (they're screwy, but there are none missing). Usually a missing closing or extra brace is the cause, as would a missing semi-colon.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I did some copy pastes from online sites and added some of my own coding.   Can you explain tell me the difference if I use $username = $_POST['username'] and $username=$_SESSION['username'];?  Is it only a session when I use the $_SESSION?  Would this still work without the session start and session destroy?  And if so, how?  I thought only cookies and sessions would allow a name remember.

Comment: You're welcome. If you plan on using sessions, then you first need to assign a variable to the session name. I have found success in using a chained method, to the effect of `$username = $_POST['username'] =  $_SESSION['username'];` works. @TheOneNOnlyQ which starts by assigning a variable `$username` then passing it on to `$_POST['username']` and in turn over to `$_SESSION['username']`

Answer (score 2):

While not the explicit cause of your EOF error,

```
if (isset($_POST['Logout'])) {
    $Logout = $_POST['Logout'];          // Okay you assigned it...

    if ($Logout == $_POST['Logout'])     // ... and now you're seeing if they're equal?
    {                                    // You want braces here...
        print "You are now logged out";
        session_destroy();     // As Fred -ii- mentioned you're missing this ;
    }                                    // ...and here
}
```

Comment: I agree on the bracing method. The OP's bracing is indeed off. I will +1 this.